Get more than 10 sub folders from microsoft graph api call using expand childFolders
I'm hitting the following end point and I expected it to return all subfolders, but it appears to default to the first 10 only. However I want to return more than 10. As such I did some searching and added $top=100 (also tried 30) but it makes no difference.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$top=100&$expand=childFolders

What is needed to get it to return the top 100 subfolders?
The full method is as follows:
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

const response = await fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$top=100&$expand=childFolders`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: headers,
});

if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error("GraphApi call failed to authenticate: " + response.statusText);
}

const data = await response.json();


$top basically applied to the base url output of the API call and does not drill down to other properties like childFolders.

Have you tried this below API?
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{parentFolderId}/childFolders?$top=100 

Try to use $top inside the $expand to override the default value of 10 child folders to be returned.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$expand=childFolders($top=100)

